# Mvvmcross Xamarin Forms Navigation page style not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm trying to style Navigation page on xamarin forms app with Mvvmcross.

before "adding" mmvcross  I've defined style in **App.xaml** as follows.

```xml
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

and it worked. I got background color and text color as i defined. Then we "moved" to Mvvmcross - we added all needed backend code, changed all pages from `ContentPage` to `MvxContentPage` etc and... background color of navigation page stopped working on Android (I haven't tried on iOS). If i change `BarTextColor` in **App.xaml** changes apply, color is changed. if i change `BackgroundColor` it also works - all application background color is changed. but no matter what value i apply to `BarBackgroundColor` it is still white.

my **App.xaml** is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<core:MvxFormsApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.ViewModels;assembly=MvvmCross"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:attributes="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Presenters.Attributes;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             x:Class="ShowMeTheLogs.Core.FormsApp">
    <core:MvxFormsApplication.Resources>
        <!--Global Styles-->
        <Color x:Key="ColorPrimary">#98C340</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ColorError">#CF1212</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ColorWarning">#E4AD17</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ColorInfo">#1283CF</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ColorDebug">#989898</Color>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SubmitButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="circleButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="smallSquareButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Micro" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </core:MvxFormsApplication.Resources>
</core:MvxFormsApplication>
```

my **App.xalm.cs** is the simpliest as it can be:

```c#
public partial class FormsApp: MvxFormsApplication
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and the simpliest view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             x:TypeArguments="viewModels:WebAppListViewModel"
             x:Class="ShowMeTheLogs.Core.Views.WebAppListPage"
             xmlns:bindings="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ShowMeTheLogs.Core.ViewModels;assembly=ShowMeTheLogs.Core"
             Title="Sample title"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="AddNewApp" Order="Secondary" Text="Dodaj aplikację" Priority="0" Command="{bindings:MvxBind NewWebAppCommand}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <RelativeLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
       <Non relevant="Code" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</views:MvxContentPage>
```

I have literally no idea why it is not working. the only change in androud code was changing `class RootActivity: CompatActivity` to `class RootActivity: MvxFormsAppCompatActivity`

have enyone fought this problem before?
packages were obtained from NuGet
- MvvmCross (and MvvmCross.Forms) ver 6.2.2
- Xamarin ver 28.0.0
- Xamarin.Forms ver 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` `OnCreate` method, make sure the two lines setting the Toolbar resource are **before** the `base.OnCreate()` call:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
}
```

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2301